# How to get user data from database?

Tags: php, mysqli

When i try to get the user data from mysql it just doesn't show anything. It's like it doesn't get anything to the $user_log.

```
if(isset($_POST['login_user']))
    {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
        $errors = array();

        if(empty($username))
        {
            array_push($errors, "Попълнете потребителското име");
        }
        if(empty($password))
        {
            array_push($errors, "Попълнете паролата");
        }

        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT 'active', 'email' FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1)
            {
                $user_log = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
                // Trying to find if there is something in 'active'
                echo 'Active: ' . $user_log['active'];
                if($user_log['active'])
                {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['success'] = "1";
                    header("location: user.php?action=panel");
                }
                else
                    array_push($errors, "Профилът не е потвърден. Има изпратен линк за потвърждение на ". $user_log['email'] .".");
            }
            else
            {
                array_push($errors, "Грешно потребителско име или парола.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get if column 'active' in the user database is 0 or 1 and if it's 0 to tell him to go confurm his email and print the user 'email' in the message.

Comment: **Warning:** You might be open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will take those advises and remake it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possibly the `echo 'Active: ' . $user_log['active'];` that you are doing before `header("location: user.php?action=panel");`

If I believe the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), you shouldn't try to display anything before calling header().

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

**EDIT :**

I just noticed that you write `$result` instead of `$results` in `$user_log = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);`. If it's still not the cause of your problem... I cannot help you, sorry.

Comment: The thing is `$user_log['active']` is not `true` so `header("location: user.php?action=panel");` is not called. The default of it is 0 i presume. I use `echo 'Active: ' . $user_log['active'];` just for debugging to see if it displays anything.

Comment: bro i feel so dumb. I've been staring on this for couple of hours straight and that's my error. Welp thanks :D